Flutter local notifications not appearing
I am developing a pill reminder app. I want to schedule notification based on interval/frequency. Ex user select 6 hour frequency and starting time of 1:00 PM, then the notification should appear at 7:00 PM. I'm having issues where notification does not appear at all. Also getting exception error when I set the expiry date later than the current date.
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:lifestyle_app/components/form_textfiel.dart';
import 'package:lifestyle_app/components/pill_button.dart';
import 'package:lifestyle_app/config.dart';
import 'package:lifestyle_app/pages/medications_page.dart';

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class AddReminder extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddReminder({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddReminder> createState() => _AddReminderState();
}

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
            (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

    var initializatonSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializatonSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
          importance: Importance.max),
    );
  }

  Future showNotification(
      {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payload}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.show(
        id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
  }

  Future scheduleNotification(
      {int id = 0,
      String? title,
      String? body,
      String? payload,
      required DateTime scheduleNotificationDateTime,
      required DateTime repeatUntil}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        tz.TZDateTime.from(
          scheduleNotificationDateTime,
          tz.local,
        ),
        await notificationDetails(),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }
}

class _AddReminderState extends State<AddReminder> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final medNameController = TextEditingController();
  final dosageController = TextEditingController();
  String frequency = "Every 1 minute";

  TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();
  DateTime expiry = DateTime.now();

  late NotificationService _notificationService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _notificationService = NotificationService();
    _notificationService.initNotification();
  }

  void addmedicine() async {
    SharedPreferences shprefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = shprefs.getString('accesstoken');

    // Schedule notification based on selectedTime and frequency
    int frequencyInMinutes = getFrequencyInMinutes(frequency);
    DateTime firstNotificationTime = DateTime.now()
        .add(Duration(minutes: getMinutesUntilNextHour() + frequencyInMinutes))
        .add(Duration(hours: selectedTime.hour, minutes: selectedTime.minute));

    // Schedule notification for each frequency interval
    for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfIntervals(expiry); i++) {
      _notificationService.scheduleNotification(
          id: i,
          title: medNameController.text,
          body: 'Time to take $medNameController.text',
          scheduleNotificationDateTime: firstNotificationTime
              .add(Duration(minutes: i * frequencyInMinutes)),
          repeatUntil: expiry);
    }

    var body = {
      'medname': medNameController.text,
      'dosage': dosageController.text,
      'frequency': frequency,
      'time': "$selectedTime",
      'expiry': expiry.toIso8601String()
    };
    print(body);

    try {
      var response = await http.patch(Uri.parse(addMedicineUrl),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Authorization': "Bearer $token"
          },
          body: jsonEncode(body));

      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MedicationsPage()));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  // Helper function to get the frequency in minutes
  int getFrequencyInMinutes(String frequency) {
    if (frequency == "Every 1 minute") {
      return 1;
    } else if (frequency == "Every 12 hours") {
      return 12 * 60;
    } else if (frequency == "Every 24 hours") {
      return 24 * 60;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  // Helper function to get the number of intervals between selectedTime and expiry
  int getNumberOfIntervals(DateTime expiry) {
    int minutesDifference =
        (expiry.difference(DateTime.now()).inHours * 60).round();
    int intervals = minutesDifference ~/ getFrequencyInMinutes(frequency);
    return intervals;
  }

  // Helper function to get the minutes until the next hour
  int getMinutesUntilNextHour() {
    int minutes = selectedTime.minute;
    if (minutes < 60 - selectedTime.minute) {
      minutes = 60 - minutes;
    } else {
      minutes = 120 - minutes;
    }
    return minutes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Image.asset(
          logo,
          height: 22,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "Add medication reminder",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 27, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    MyTextField(
                        formKey: _formKey,
                        isPassword: false,
                        controller: medNameController,
                        label: "Medicine name",
                        errorMsg: "Enter the medicine name",
                        height: height),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.04,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: MyTextField(
                              formKey: _formKey,
                              isPassword: false,
                              controller: dosageController,
                              label: "Dosage",
                              errorMsg: "Enter the dosage",
                              height: height),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(
                            "mg",
                            style: TextStyle(color: fontColor2, fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                        DropdownButton(
                          value: frequency,
                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_outlined),
                          style: TextStyle(color: fontColor2),
                          onChanged: (String? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              frequency = value!;
                            });
                          },
                          items: const [
                            DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: "Every 1 minute",
                              child: Text("Every 1 minute"),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: "Every 12 hours",
                              child: Text("Every 12 hours"),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: "Every 24 hours",
                              child: Text("Every 24 hours"),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.04,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            "Start time:",
                            style: TextStyle(color: fontColor2, fontSize: 17),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            "${selectedTime.hour}:${selectedTime.minute}",
                            style: TextStyle(color: fontColor1, fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              final TimeOfDay? timeofday = await showTimePicker(
                                  context: context,
                                  initialTime: selectedTime,
                                  initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.dial);
                              if (timeofday != null) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedTime = timeofday;
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            child: Text("Set time"))
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.04,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            "Expiry date:",
                            style: TextStyle(color: fontColor2, fontSize: 17),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            DateFormat('d MMM yyyy').format(expiry),
                            style: TextStyle(color: fontColor1, fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              showDatePicker(
                                      context: context,
                                      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
                                      lastDate: DateTime(2100))
                                  .then((value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  if (value != null) {
                                    expiry = value!;
                                  }
                                });
                              });
                            },
                            child: Text("Set date"))
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 250,
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        child: Material(
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                addmedicine();
                              }
                            },
                            child: MyPillButton(
                                width: 110.0,
                                height: 50.0,
                                color: appBlue,
                                text: "Save",
                                textcolor: Colors.white,
                                fontweight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Did you validate these problems? Did you read the documentation carefully and configure both platforms correctly? Both OSes have different constraints to alarms and background work, so make sure you configure everything correctly.
